# POST Request for Ionic using Ripple in Chrome Browser

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, ionic-framework, ripple, post-redirect-get

I am rather new to Ionic App development and need help.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 for development and Chrome Browser with Ripple for rendering the application.

The problem is, when making an Ajax Post request to an API it gives me a 404 (Not Found error) because the **POST url gets prepended with a rippleApi and TinyHippos Uri**.

I am wondering what causes this prepending of the URI

The following is my Controller:

```
var request = $http({
      method: "post",
      url: myPostLink,
      data: {},
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  });
  request.success(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: Have u solved this..?